# Automatically stop a terminal script when locking MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, bash

I have written a bash script that I manually start when logging in onto the laptop, but I want it to stop running when I lock my laptop.

This doesn't seem a very standard scenario, but I don't want to always manually stop the bash script when I go for a bathroom break and lock my MacBook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could modify your script with a while loop, that tests if you have locked the screen or not.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505255/osx-check-if-the-screen-is-locked) is a python approach, that checks for an active session.

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575715/mixed-shell-and-python-script-possible) is a way on implementing this python part into a bash script.

The answer in the first link also provides a Shell implementation, that could work for you too, but I was unsure, so I gave you another link.

**Update** : 
Because I wanted to solve the problem, here is what I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash
loop=$(python -c 'import sys,Quartz; d=Quartz.CGSessionCopyCurrentDictionary(); print d' | grep "CGSSessionScreenIsLocked = 1")
while [ "$loop" = "" ]; do
    echo "not locked"
    loop=$(python -c 'import sys,Quartz; d=Quartz.CGSessionCopyCurrentDictionary(); print d' | grep "CGSSessionScreenIsLocked = 1")
done
echo "locked"
```

However, If your script is one giant task, then the while loop won't help you.

In general, I think, it is rather difficult to trigger something on system lock. You probably need some helper application that watches the process and stops it when you lock the screen.

Taking this a step further : You could write a small programm/script that can check if your script is running and pause it, and when you are back at your desk and unlock the screen, it continues.

Comment: Works perfectly!